# Android APK from Rails Server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've stored my .apk file in my rails server. I've set up a route that redirects a given url to a method that essentially sends the file

in my routes.rb file

```
match '/myApk.apk' to: 'upgradeapk#index'
```

Upgradeapk_controller.rb file

```
def index    
     @filename = '/myApk/myApk.apk'
     @tmpfile = 'upgradedApk.apk' 
     send_file(@filename, :disposition => 'inline', :stream => true,  :type=> 'application/vnd.android.package-archive', :file_name => @tmpfile)
end
```

When i type my sever url and add '/myApk.apk' it starts the downloading process as long as i do it on my a computer. However if i try to do it on my android device it doesn't work. Checking the download lists in my android device browser i notice that the download "job" for the apk is created, however its in an endless loop changing between states "in queue" and "downloading". Nothing ever downloads.

Do I have to set the send_file differently when it comes to making it work on android devices?

----*EDIT*------

Ok so i've decided to store the files in a dropbox location instead of storing it in my server. If i pass the url for the file directly in my android function for the http request, it works well. The file is found, downloaded and the installation is prompted.

```
class UpgradeapkController < ApplicationController
    def index
            android_apk = Androidaplicacion.first (Model to access the table in which i store the apk dropbox url)
            route = android_apk.url
            redirect_to route
    end
```

end

I've set up my controller to redirect to the given url for the dropbox file. If i try the url (same as before, using the "match" url) in my android browser, this time it downloads. However, if I try it from the android app, its the same as before, it just doesnt download.

So, the "send_file" method seems to not be working if its on the android platform. redirecting to my dropbox url from the controller works on android but only from a browser, not using the http request on my android app. The only way to get it to work in my android app is if I use the dropbox direct link.

Also, I first thought this was because my server was running on https and the certificate its not a valid one. I found a way to bypass the https certification encryption/certificate validation thing on my android app but it didnt work either (it appeared to have succeed in avoiding the validation) but the results ended up been the same. I then ran an instance of my server using http and still same results.